# How to install componentjs builder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I need componentjs to build a javascript library taken from github.

Then I installed Node.js for Windows 64bits, and when I try to install componentjs or component-builder, I get the following errors that I don't understand:

```
C:\Users\Kevin>npm install component
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://githu
b.com/ariya/esprima.git) undefined
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://githu
b.com/ariya/esprima.git) undefined
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/ariya/esprima.git undefined
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/ariya/esprima.git undefined
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "component"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Kevin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kevin\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check if you have git installed and in your PATH

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was that I didn't installed msysgit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to CD..

Just install msysgit (git for windows).
During the installation, it's prompted if you want to automatically add git to your PATH environment variable.